# Question about the Minimum Modulus Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve following exercise:

> Exercise: Let $B \subset \mathbb{C}$. Does a non-constant holomorphic
> function $f:B \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ exist such that $|f|$ has a
> local minimum in $U$.

It seems obvious that the Minimum Principle is the key for this exercise.

> Minimum Principle  Let $f$ be holomorphic on $G$. If there exists a
> point $c \in G$ such that there exists a neighborhood $U \subset G$ of
> c such that $|f(c)|=inf_{z \in U}|f(z)|$. Then $f(c)=0$, or $f$ is
> constant in $G$

Depending on that, my answer would be yes there exits a non-constant function.

My Problem is, I don't really understand why $f$ needs to be constant or have a zero in $c$. More precisely, I understand why $f$ needs to be constant, (because if I use the maximum principle on $1/f$ the result follows easily) but why can $f(c)$ be zero?.

Comment: A zero must necessarily be a local minimum of the modulus because the modulus is non negative. The minimum modulus principle states that this is the only such scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the maximum principle on $1/f$ if $f$ has a zero in $U$.